# JS Add to array with Spread Operator if non-NULL - Expression Syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to get an array resulting from the original array `props.ids` and conditionally (if not NULL) the variable `selectedId` appended. The following works, but the syntax doesn't look right. I need the `selectedId &&` to check for non-NULL, and if so add `selectedId`. Is there a better syntax for this small expression?

```
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

obj = {
        'exclude':[...props.ids, selectedId && selectedId]}
      }
```

Comment: Why aren't you passing up the id to the parent component to manage the state rather having this component accept ids and then have to manage the state itself?

Comment: The parent ID has the original list but some additions can be made from this component directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one line way

```
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

obj = {
        exclude:[...props.ids, ...(selectedId === null ? [] : [selectedId])]}
      }
```

Proper way

```
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

obj = {
        exclude: [...props.ids]
      }

if (selectedId !== null) {
    obj.exclude.push(selectedId)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition Ananth's answer, you could also use the ternary operator inline

```js
const ids = [1, 2, 3];

let item = null;
let resultWhenNull = [...ids, ...(item ? [item] : [])];
console.log(resultWhenNull);

item = 4;
const resultWhenNonNull = [...ids, ...(item ? [item] : [])];
console.log(resultWhenNonNull);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Ternary operator or a simple if statement to accomplish this

```js
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

const obj = {};

// if selectedId is present append selectedId, else return array of props.ids
obj['exclude'] = selectedId ? [...props.ids, selectedId] : [...props.ids]
```

```js
const value = false;
const props = [1, 2, 3];
const valToAppend = 4;
const obj = {};
obj['test'] = value ? [...props, valToAppend] : [...props];

console.log(obj);
```